# Returning more than one object in Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to return two items to an html file in Flask and am having trouble figuring out the best way to do it.

The two operative lines Flask is pulling from in a separate file are:

```
                                            # trader_db = Blotter(1000000, collection)
cash = self.cash + df['Value'].sum()        # trader_db.cash
return df.to_html('templates/pnlstmt.html') # trader_db.pnl(collection)
```

with this code:

```
@app.route("/pl")
def show_pl():
    cash = trader_db.cash
    trader_db.pnl(collection)
    return render_template('pnlstmt.html'), cash
```

I get the expected P&L

```
Symbol  Position
AAPL    350.0
AMZN    1000.0
GOOG    350.0
```

But the cash isn't displayed.

Is there a way I can get show_pl() to display both objects?

I tried to make cash a DataFrame and concatenate but that threw an error.

Comment: You are doing it wrong way :) Rendering data into html file on disk and then using it as a template is a bad practice. You could either keep html representation of dataframe as string variable and add any desired content to it as an plain html, or, the better way, use real template file with Jinja syntaxis. In second option you will pass your variables to the 'render_template' function and use them inside the template.

Comment: Nice tutorial for the second case: https://damyanon.net/post/flask-series-templating/

Comment: I'm a noob at Flask, can you point me in the right direction? 
-edit Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to separate "logic" from "presentation". Using python function you calculate values. And using template system you structure it in a presentable html view.

I wrote simple example that might be helpful for you:

First, we calculate data (I have a stub here) and pass them to the template context as variables:

```
from flask import app, render_template
import pandas as pd

main = app.Flask("app")

@main.route('/pnl')
def pnl():
    df = pd.DataFrame([["AAPL","AMZN","GOOG"], [350.0,1000.0,350.0]], index=["Symbol","Position"]).T
    cash = 100000

    # passing data to the template
    return render_template("pnl.html", data=df, cash=cash)

main.run(port=8889)
```

Second, we create template which "renders" our data into html. This is the content of `pnl.html` file:

```
<table>
{% for ind,row in data.iterrows() %}
    <tr><td>{{ind}}</td><td>{{row["Symbol"]}}</td><td>{{row["Position"]}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<h2>Total cash: {{ cash }}</h2>
```

This is a complete code to launch and test it.